# Android parse urls from JSONArray in Textview and make them clickable

Tags: android, json, hyperlink, clickable

I'm currently parsing JSON in my android app (note that I am quite new to this stuff; both android and JSON). Now I got a JSONObject and inside this object a JSONArray with links (strings) inside them. 
I'd like to put these links inside the array inside a Textview and make them also clickable.

Using Log.w i could retrieve the following output:

```
<a href="http://xxxx.xx/xxxx/test.xlsx">test.xlsx</a>
```

The URL seems valid, but everything I try to make them actually be links seem to fail.
This is the code that I use to retrieve the links:

```
ArrayList<String> map; //note it's already filled and contains strings like the example
sb = new StringBuilder("Items in map:\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<map.size();i++){
        sb.append(Html.fromHtml("&#8226; " + map.get(i) + "<br/>"));
    }
```

Now I "empty" the stringbuilder into my TextView:

```
   TextView overView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textOverView);
    overView.setText(sb.toString());
    //make links clickable?
    overView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I've also tried to use Linkify, the android:clickable properties, url encoders and many more, but unfortunately nothing seems to work. If I remove the setMoveMent method the links are not even blue (let alone clickable), the same goes for all the other methods.

Any ideas are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

`MovementMethod` makes links clickable and selectable. But you need `ClickableSpan` instances attached to your text first so the `MovementMethod` can work. This is done by `Linkify` and the `MovementMethod` is just so that it can be selected within a large body of text. I think what you are asking for is this,

```
android:autoLink="all"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

This was just have the textview link all links it recognizes with `ClickableSpan` instances and setup the proper `MovementMethod`.

Comment: It didn't work. I've added these 2 to my TextView. The (even without these 2 lines added) links are not visible as link, but just as plain text. In other words <a href="google.com">Hey there!</a> shows as Hey there! yet the line is not clickable and not blue either.

Comment: so your string build is stripping out all the formatting. Don't use the fromHtml() call on each iteration. Use it on the StringBuilder after you are done appending everything.